# Generating a constrained directed graph from an adjacency matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have written the following `Code`

```
Clear[n, d, A, mm, G];
SeedRandom[14];
n = 10;
A = Array[RandomReal[{0, 0.5}] &, {n, n}];
mm = SetPrecision[Inverse[IdentityMatrix[n] - A], 2];

selectionMatrix[θ_] := ReplacePart[mm, {i_, i_} -> 0] /.
{x_ /; x > θ -> 1, x_ /; x < θ -> 0} // Transpose;

v = Table[Subscript[s, i], {i, n}];
g = AdjacencyGraph[selectionMatrix[0.05], 
VertexLabels -> MapThread[Rule, {Range
[Length[v]], v}], ImageSize -> 150, VertexSize -> .9, ImagePadding -> 20];

{selectionMatrix[0.05] // MatrixForm, g}
```

`selectionMatrix` works just fine for a single parameter `theta` defining the threshold for creating an adjacency matrix represented as a directed graph. The parameter `theta` defines a binary selection, i.e., selecting those elements of a matrix that are below or above the `theta` level.

I want to modify the `selectionMatrix` function in such a way to create an adjacency matrix for a range of `theta` such as `0.5<theta<1` or `-0.4<theta<0.2` etc. How can I revise `selectionMatrix` to accomplish this task?

[image]

Comment: does this work: `ClearAll[selectionMatrix2];
selectionMatrix2[m_][\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := 
 Transpose[(1 - UnitStep[\[Theta]1 - m]) (1 - 
      UnitStep[m - \[Theta]2])] - IdentityMatrix[Length@m]`?

Comment: yes. For the two examples in your question, you can use it as `selectionMatrix2[mm][.5,1]` and `selectionMatrix2[mm][-.4,.2]`

Comment: @TugrulTemel Have also a look at `Clip`.

Comment: @kglr: Unfortunately, it does not give the correct result. Given a matrix `mm = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, -1, -2, -3}, {0, 1, -3, 3}, {3, 4, 5, -5}}`, `selectionMatrix2[mm][-2, 2]` (elements within the range (-2,2) should be all 1, otherwise 0, including diagonals) yields `{{0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}}`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [BoolEval](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/BoolEval) package:

```
<< BoolEval`

BoolEval[0.5 < Range[0, 1, 0.1] < 1]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0} *)

BoolEval[0.5 < Range[0, 1, 0.1] <= 1]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

You can use it on the `mm` matrix.

Also check out `IGZeroDiagonal` from IGraph/M for efficiently and reliably zeroing out a diagonal of a matrix.

Comment: I installed `IGraph` but `BoolEval` does not work properly. I receive the following warning: Get::noopen: Cannot open BoolEval`while I have the currently installed versions of IGraph/M are: {Paclet[IGraphM,0.3.108,<>],Paclet[IGraphM,0.3.103,<>]}. What is the problem here?

Comment: @TugrulTemel These are two independent packages. It looks like you did not install BoolEval.

Comment: @TugrulTemel In recent versons of Mathematica, `PacletInstall["https://github.com/szhorvat/BoolEval/releases/download/v1.0.0/BoolEval-1.0.0.paclet"]`

Comment: I found the way to enter a matrix. Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is just the *probabilities* that matter, not the thresholds:

```
theta2 = .6;
theta1 = .4;
g = RandomGraph[
BernoulliGraphDistribution[10, Abs[theta2 - theta1]]]
```

[image]

```
MatrixForm[AdjacencyMatrix[g]]
```

[image]